# Equivalent of viewDidAppear in RCTViewManager

Tags: ios, react-native

I've created a custom view for a react-native app, which is itself a C++ DSP application and runs on a timer. The view is initialised on startup using it's `init` method. However in order to save CPU cycles I need to know when the view is visible or not.

If I was using an iOS UIViewController I could employ `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` to send the message to the C++ code to start the timer, and `viewDidDisappear` to tell it to stop.

I'm looking for a clean way to do the same from within an RCTViewManager.

Comment: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/native-view-controllers-and-react-native/ may help.